IBM Maximo: Trying to write query on Workorder (Tr) with all workorders that do not have an attachment
Here's what I have so far.
(((status = 'CAN' or status = 'CLOSE' or status = 'COMP' and exists (
  select *
  from doclinks
  where document IS NULL))))

I've also tried...
and exists (
select 1 from doclinks
where document in ( 
    select value from synonymdomain
    where domainid = 'DOCUMENT'
    and value IS NULL)

Thanks in advance for help
